# rails runner ignored subdirectory RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relative-path, runner

Using rails 4.2.0.beta4.

It looks like the env `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` is ignored when running scripts by runner. It works on my webserver when not using runner. But with runner I get this:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/somewhere ./bin/rails runner "puts Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.branches_path"
=> /branches # should be /somewhere/branches
```

The env is set correctly:

```
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/somewhere ./bin/rails runner "puts ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']"
=> /somewhere
```

I also tried to set it in the config with no luck:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/somewhere'
config.relative_url_root = '/somewhere'
```

How can I make the runner respect the subdirectory/`RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT`?

For my webserver (unicorn btw) it works by starting it with the following `config.ru` (which is not used by runner afaik):

```
run Rack::URLMap.new(
      ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] => Rails.application
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known rails bug and hopefully will be fixed soon: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17724